# Using okhttp for simple get request in Kotlin helper class

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

just started learning Kotlin. I'm trying to use okhttp to send a simple get request to a URL that contains only text.

I want the output of the request stored in a liveData variable, but when I run it, it crashes. Here's the class:

```
// gradle dependency added to build.gradle:
// implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.5.0")
//
// added this permission to AndroidManifest.xml just above the "application" section
// <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
//

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import java.io.IOException



class GetExample {
    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    private val _theResult = MutableLiveData<String?>()
    val theResult: LiveData<String?> = _theResult
   

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getText(url: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute()
                .use { response -> _theResult.value = response.body?.string() }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            _theResult.value = e.message
        }
    }
}
```

And to call this I'm using

```
val url = "https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md"
GetExample().getText(url)
```

and accessing the result with

```
var thisString: String? = GetExample().theResult.value
```

Help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break down a little what your code does, shall we?

```kotlin
val url = "https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md"
GetExample().getText(url)

var thisString: String? = GetExample().theResult.value
```

You first assign the url variable to be a github link. Then, you construct a new GetExample object and call getText on it, with the url parameter.
But now, you are assigning thisString to a *new* instance of GetExample, which means it doesn't contain the data from the object you called getText on.

To fix this problem, one might write something like this:

```kotlin
val url = "https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md"
val getter = GetExample()
getter.getText(url)

var thisString: String? = getter.theResult.value
```

What george said is true as well, but I haven't tested that so you need to take a look if that is a problem as well.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I got everything working with both of your tips, a separate thread and cleared up that logic error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute this on the UI thread. That will not work.
Just try to run it on another thread, like the IO Thread,
and use `postValue` in `liveData`. Otherwise, you need to set the value on the UI thread.

E.g.,

```
try {
    runBlocking(IO) {
        client.newCall(request).execute()
            .use { response -> _theResult.postValue(response.body?.string()) }
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    _theResult.value = e.message
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried messing around with coroutines but couldn't get it right so I went with a simple Thread{ }.start() around the function call and now it works great!